# How to fix Uncaught TypeError: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string?

Tags: php, xml, string, error-handling, sitemap

I am unsure how to fix the following error in my Magento2 sitemap module: Uncaught TypeError: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, null given in /var/www/html/app/code/SEO/XmlSitemap/Model/Writer.php:388

```
 protected function getImageXml(DataObject $images): string
    {
        $xml = '';
        foreach ($images->getCollection() as $image) {

            $this->imageCount++;
            $preparedImageUrl     = htmlspecialchars($image->getUrl());
            $preparedThumbnailUrl = htmlspecialchars($images->getThumbnail());
            $preparedTitle        = htmlspecialchars($images->getTitle());
            $preparedCaption      = $image->getCaption() ? htmlspecialchars($image->getCaption()) : '';

            $xmlImage = $this->getWrappedString($preparedImageUrl, 'image:loc');
            $xmlImage .= $this->getWrappedString($preparedTitle, 'image:title');
            if ($preparedCaption) {
                $xmlImage .= $this->getWrappedString($preparedCaption, 'image:caption');
            }

            $xml .= $this->getWrappedString($xmlImage, 'image:image');
        }
```

Line 388 is the following line:

```
$preparedTitle        = htmlspecialchars($images->getTitle());
```

The generation of the products sitemap.xml file, which is what this module is intended to do, returns a 500 error. How can I fix this?

Comment: `var_dump($images->getTitle());` before the bad part of the code runs. Is it a string?

Comment: If it's a null you should really figure out why. However in some cases you get integers that throw a fit with string functions, and there you can simply `(string) $value` them. Don't do that with `null` though, figure out why it's null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$images->getTitle()` method does not return a string. Are you sure you need to call this on the `$images` and not the `$image` variable? Even then you might want to be explicit:

```php
$values = [
  'filled string' => 'string', 
  'empty string' => '', 
  'null value' => NULL, 
  'false value' => false, 
  'falsy value' => 0
];

foreach ($values as $label => $value) {
  echo "\n", $label, "\n"; 
  var_dump(
   [
     // original value
     $value, 
     // explicit string cast
     (string)$value, 
     // fallback if null or undefined
     $value ?? 'default', 
     // fallback if falsy
     $value ?: 'default'
   ]
  );
}
```

```
filled string
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "string"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "string"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "string"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "string"
}

empty string
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
  [2]=>
  string(0) ""
  [3]=>
  string(7) "default"
}

null value
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  NULL
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
  [2]=>
  string(7) "default"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "default"
}

false value
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  bool(false)
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
  [2]=>
  bool(false)
  [3]=>
  string(7) "default"
}

falsy value
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  int(0)
  [1]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [2]=>
  int(0)
  [3]=>
  string(7) "default"
}
```